# Jquery related IE bug attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Ok so I'm a newbie in Jquery and have this simple script to 'preview' an image in a div on clicking 2 links

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function(){
    $('a.classname').click(function(){ 

        var new_image_src = $(this).attr('href');
        var $new_image = $("<img>", {
            src:    new_image_src,
            width:  400,
            height: 300,
            load:   function() {
                $('#preview').animate({'opacity': 1}, 'fast');
            }
        });

        $('#preview').animate({'opacity': 0}, 'fast', function(){
            $('#preview').empty().append($new_image);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

.....

<a class="classname" href="images/pic1.png">link 1</a>
<a class="classname" href="images/pic2.png">link 2</a>
```

Works great in Firefox and Opera . IE however opens a new window on click to the path of the image (www.mysite.com/images/pic1.png).

I've know this is IE behavior and not a jquery bug ..but is there a simple workaround to suit all browsers?

Comment: test it     $("a.classname").click(function(event) {
   var new_image_src = $(this).attr('href');
        var $new_image = $("<img>", {
            src:    new_image_src,
            width:  400,
            height: 300,
            load:   function() {
                $('#preview').animate({'opacity': 1}, 'fast');
            }
        });

        $('#preview').animate({'opacity': 0}, 'fast', function(){
            $('#preview').empty().append($new_image);
        });
});

Comment: @AEMLoviji, why didn't you just post that as an answer?

Comment: if my answer will help to user i will add it as answer

Comment: @AEMLoviji: If it's an answer, you should add it as an answer. BTW I think you forgot the `event.preventDefault()` line.

Comment: yes i forget to add it. thanks for help

Comment: user685951, will you test it?

Comment: You can test it here : jsfiddle.net/pnTM4/2 .I have test it in IE, Opera, Chrome and FF. it works great

Answer (score 1):

try this:

**1-** Replace this line :

```
$('a.classname').click(function(){
```

with this one:

```
$('a.classname').click(function(event){
```

**2-** Replace this line :

```
return false;
```

with this one:

`event.preventDefault();`

and let me know if it works, and I will tell you what is going on here :)

Comment: Nope..Still the same behavior unfortunately... Works great in Firefox and Opera ...still returns a URL in IE

Comment: +1 This is the right way to stop events in jQuery. `return false` only works for attribute events.

Answer (score 0):

test it please

```
$(function () {
     $("a.classname").click(function(event) 
     { 
      event.preventDefault();
      var new_image_src = $(this).attr('href');
        var $new_image = $("<img>", {
            src:    new_image_src,
            width:  400,
            height: 300,
            load:   function() {
                $('#preview').animate({'opacity': 1}, 'fast');
            }
        });

        $('#preview').animate({'opacity': 0}, 'fast', function(){
            $('#preview').empty().append($new_image);
        });
     });
   };
```

[event.preventDefault() --> Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

[test it here](http://look%20here%20jsfiddle.net/AEMLoviji/pnTM4/2/)

Comment: same results as before :( All I am trying to do is just preview an image on a div called 'preview' . Annoying that IE doesn't realize this !